# Как добавить фоновые изображение к ссылке

Tags: ссылки, skype

Обмениваясь ссылками через скайп, я вижу превью [ссылки](http://take.ms/ayWoT).

Что это за технология? Как реализовать на своем сайте?

Comment: Не размещайте изображения на сторонних ресурсах.

Answer (score 0):

для каждого сервиса свои мета теги в хэде

это нужно в СЕО искать

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="ru_RU" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Создание и продвижение сайтов - WEBFORFRIENDS" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Создание и продвижение сайтов, seo оптимизация, продвижение в интернете - веб для друзей" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://webforfriends.com/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="web for friends" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1737845629838725" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://webforfriends.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/webforfriends-social.jpg" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"/>
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Создание и продвижение сайтов, seo оптимизация, продвижение в интернете - веб для друзей"/>
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Создание и продвижение сайтов - WEBFORFRIENDS"/>
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="web for friends"/>
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="http://webforfriends.com/wp-content/themes/webforfriends/images/bg-social.jpg"/>
```